# MyButtons which is below ViewPager goes up with SoftKeyboard when focus is in edittext in TABLAYOUT

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/create_case_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/lb_background"
    tools:context="com.cubesquaretech.lawbuddy.Activity.CreateCaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/create_case_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTextPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_above="@id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view"
            android:layout_above="@id/btn_next"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is  the `xml` code for `Activity` containing `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`
The Buttons are below pager which comes up with `softkeyboard` when focuses on `edittext`.

I want that `softkeyboard` to open without buttons coming up.
I used `SoftInuptKeyboard` Hide in manifest that works for me.

First time the `SoftInuptKeyboard` doesnt open when we open it by clicking on
`editext` then it works fine the buttons don't come up with keyboard.

If I remove the below code from manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

then the button goes up with `SoftInuptKeyboard`

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: I used that but my softkeyboard not coming up

Comment: I want soft key to come but not that buttons below pager

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" try this

Comment: Buttons coming up with softkeyboard